# User Regsitartion Jmeter Script

Tags: jmeter

I have to write a jmeter script for a user registation process using Blazemeter. I have recorded for 1 user but for different users will need unique data like DOB, Address, unique email id. Which feature shall i use. Kindly share your thoughts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which you can use for generating randomized data, for example:

- [`__RandomDate()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomDate) - produces random date in the given range in the given pattern
- Address and Email - if random string will be OK you can generate them using [`__RandomString()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) function

If you need more "real" data you can take a look at [JavaFaker](https://www.baeldung.com/java-faker) library which produces realistic names/emails, you will need to have the [javafaker.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.javafaker/javafaker/1.0.2) along with its dependencies in JMeter Classpath and you will be able to call its methods using [`__groovy()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function

Check out [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction) article for more information on JMeter Functions concept